# confusing syntax error?

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

i am getting this error here

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /home/u423419659/public_html/install/install.php on line 44
```

I am pretty sure i follow all correct procedures, why is it giving this error?

```
 public function SozcuguSifrele( $NEYI )
    {
        $result = "";
        $i = 0;
        while ( $i < ( $NEYI ) )
        {
            $char = ( $NEYI, $i, 1 );
            $keychar = ( $this->AnahtarKelime, $i % ( $this->AnahtarKelime ) - 1, 1 );
            $char = ( ( $char ) + ( $keychar ) );
            $result .= $char;
            ++$i;
        }
        return ( ( $result ) );
```

line 44 would be the this part

```
$char = ( $NEYI, $i, 1 );
```

Comment: What is that line supposed to do?

Comment: Are you sure your code does what you think it does? Those commas probably should be something else.

Comment: i am sorry i d.l this script from turkish site, from what i can understand from the readme it calls de-ion cube

Comment: Are you sure the original script is a PHP script?

Comment: yes, i thought it was something obvious that i was missing, guess not, i will test some things and edit original post

Answer (score 1):

Here is my best guess.

This looks to be a rather odd sort of implementation of a one time pad encryption algorithm.  The reason why your code is crashing is you somehow lost the function name from that particular line.

```
        $char = ( $NEYI, $i, 1 );
```

Is probably supposed to be

```
        $char = substr( $NEYI, $i, 1 );
```

This would also explain why there seems to be many extra parenthesis.  You're probably missing functions from the other lines of code:

```
        $keychar = ( $this->AnahtarKelime, $i % ( $this->AnahtarKelime ) - 1, 1 );
```

Should probably be:

```
        $keychar = substr( $this->AnahtarKelime, $i % strlen( $this->AnahtarKelime ) - 1, 1 );
```

I would recommend trying to find an unmodified source, but reimplementation shouldn't be terribly difficult now that you know what you're doing.

Comment: Beyond my proper answer though, the encryption algorithm described here should NEVER EVER EVER be used in something important.  It is far too weak.  Use `mcrypt_encrypt` instead.  It will also save you a bunch of work. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php

Comment: hello guys, apparently this was the decoded functions from someone' elses script, i searched day and night for an proper decoder as i have the source (guy who wrote this for me left encoded it) and have not found anything, bearing a miracle i think right now its helpless